# ObservableObject is updating all views and causing menus to close in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this class which calls an API every 3 seconds (using a timer) and saves the result in the `@Published` array named `items`:

```
public class ApiAdapter: ObservableObject {

    @Published var items = [Item]()
    
    init() {
        
        api = Api(...)
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: true) { timer in
            api.getItems() { items in 
                if let _items = items {
                    self.items = _items
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The ApiAdapter is used throughout the entire app so I decided to make it an `@EnvironmentObject`.
In the main view of my app I'm accessing the `apiAdapter.items` array for displaying it in a list like so:

```
struct MainListView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var apiAdapter: ApiAdapter
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(apiAdapter.items, id: \.hash) { i in
                    Text(i.name)
                    ...
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                Menu {
                                    Picker(selection: $category, label: Text("Filter")) {
                                        Text("Category 1").tag(1)
                                        Text("Category 2").tag(2)
                                        Text("Category 3").tag(3)
                                    }
                                } label: {
                                    Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3.decrease.circle")
                                        .imageScale(.large)
                                }
        }
    }
}
```

In MainListView I have also some `Menu`s in the `navigationBar` which get closed every time the `apiAdapter` updates the `items` variable, so it makes it hard to use them.

How is it possible to update only the list and not the entire view? or even better how is it possible to update only the items that changed in the last api call?

Comment: Would you prepare reproducible example for this?

Comment: @Asperi well, I can improve the code provided in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `EnvironmentObject` from your MainListView. Create a new View for the List only like this:

```
struct ListView : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var apiAdapter: ApiAdapter

    var body : some View {
        List {
            ForEach(apiAdapter.items, id: \.hash) { i in
                Text(i.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now your subview only updates, while your main view remains the same and the Menu remains opened.

And your MainListView as follows:

```
struct MainListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ListView() //<< here comes your ListView which refreshes independent
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, from what I understand, having an ObservableObject in a view makes the view refresh every time the object changes. Since I need the ApiAdapter in other parts of the code and I don't want them to update every time, what's the best way to implement that?

Comment: Basically your environment object is pushed to all your subviews. If you want to use it and make the view "react" / refresh on changes, you include the definition at the top. If you don't want the view to refresh don't add it. If you need it at some other points you might create another subview for it to be independent. Maybe you can also just build your main view with the Navigation View and the button and pass everything to subviews.